# how to clone an ember object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a model named "user" which is like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   bankAccounts: DS.attr()
})
```

within the app, when user goes to the end page and hits finish, bankAccouunts property is set to an array of bankaccounts which looks like this

```
 bankAccount {
   bankName:
   address:
   accountInfo: [] (again an array)
   membersInfo: [{Object1}, {Object2}] (array with json objects)
}
```

Now when I create a model of user and do _model.save() then as per adapter createRecord method, it does not serialize the inner attributes (by serialization, I meant converting camelCase to snakeCase, for example: bankAccounts will be converted to bank_accounts.)

Now the questions is:

is there a way to serialize inner attributes too? (say i want to serialize membersInfo to member_info)

I hope this will clarify my doubts, if not I am happy to edit again and request assistance.

Comment: In which way the object gets modified second time? could you provide an example?

Comment: What type is `value1`? What version of ember are you using?

Comment: I will update the question with the code and the problem I have figured out in some time :)

Answer (score 2):

probably you should write a [custom transform](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.Transform). Then you can use it like this:

```
bankAccounts: DS.attr('my-transform')
```

The [ember string functions like `dasherize`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.4/classes/String/methods/dasherize?anchor=dasherize) are probably pretty useful for this.

Answer (score 2):

In general I would recommend to model `bankAccounts` as a has-many relationship between `user` and `bank-account` models. Otherwise you can't update a specific bank account without updating the user modal and replacing all bank accounts. Also it would not be possible to use a specific bank account for navigation as they don't have an ID. Ember Data has [powerful relationship support](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/relationships/). In that case you wouldn't have an issue with serialization of your attribute cause it's another model having a fully powered [Serializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/).

If for some reason you don't want to have a separate bank account model and use a one-to-many relationship, you have two options:

- Writing a custom transform for serialization as recommended by @Lux.
- Using [`ember-data-model-fragments`](https://github.com/lytics/ember-data-model-fragments) which supports Serializer even for attributes of a model.

Comment: Thanks, the use case I have restricts me to use ember relationships and hence I was using model fragments like you mentioned. The complication was, my model has a fragment array which itself has a fragment array. The deeper fragments were not getting serialized. I tried something different and it worked, but I feel model fragments do not get serialized if you try to serialize the model they are contained in. Someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: [The docs stating that](https://github.com/lytics/ember-data-model-fragments#nesting) *"nesting of fragments is fully supported"*.